# Concatenate letter A to cells of a specific column with the condition that the cells of the same column does not CONTAIN B

Tags: mysql

I want to concatenate a letter C to the column area where area does not CONTAIN B.   [mytable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATPDc.png) and my command is : `select concat(area, ' ,C') as area FROM emplistdb.t_test where area NOT LIKE '%B%'`.

Comment: The problem is that i can't save the result after the execution of the command ?? and if there is an easier way to do that.

Comment: What you mean when you say  `save the result`

Comment: it is a SELECT statement !!! i mean make the change... concat  letter C and apply the change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UPDATE` query if you want to update the value, e.g.:

```
UPDATE t_test
SET area = concat(area, ' ,C')
WHERE area NOT LIKE '%B%';
```

Comment: I used yours like : UPDATE emplistdb.t_test SET area = concat(area, ' ,ط') WHERE area NOT LIKE '%ش%';  i got an error :                              Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

Comment: I did this and it worked fine :  - SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
-UPDATE emplistdb.t_test SET area = concat(area, ' ,ط') WHERE area NOT LIKE '%ش%';
-SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;